# lbfgs: how to find gradient

Tags: r, math, optimization, gradient

I want to use lbfgs method for minimizing function. Problem is that the function is Svenson function (see: [Svenson function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/YieldCurve/versions/4.1/topics/Svensson)) and I do not know how to find gradient of such function, where tau (time) goes from 1:15.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the gradient. Take the partials wrt each of the variables.

[image]

We can numerically check the gradient is correct.

```
grad=function(t, b0, b1, b2, b3, l1, l2) {
  a=1
  b=exp(-t/l1)
  c=t/l1*exp(-t/l1)
  d=t/l2*exp(-t/l2)
  e=t*exp(-t/l1)*(b1*l1+b2*(t-l1))/l1^3
  f=-b3*t*exp(-t/l2)*(l2-t)/l2^3
  return(c(a,b,c,d,e,f))
}
func=function(t, b0, b1, b2, b3, l1, l2) {
  return(b0+b1*exp(-t/l1)+b2*t/l1*exp(-t/l1)+b3*t/l2*exp(-t/l2))
}
x0=c(runif(6))
x1=x0+rnorm(6, 0, .01)

f0=func(1, x0[1], x0[2], x0[3], x0[4], x0[5], x0[6])
f0grd=grad(1, x0[1], x0[2], x0[3], x0[4], x0[5], x0[6])
f1=func(1, x1[1], x1[2], x1[3], x1[4], x1[5], x1[6])
f1-f0
0.009506896

sum(f0grd * (x1-x0))
0.009467063
```

Comment: what should I do with tau? If, it goes from 1:15

Comment: Is that all the information you are given? fit a svensson model with tau from 1:15? or is there more information/data. E.g. what are the observed y-values at tau=1:15.

Comment: observed y values are: 3.64  3.58  3.54  3.53  3.54  3.58  3.64  3.71  3.80   3.90   4.10   4.13   4.26   4.40   4.54, respectively for 1:15

Comment: I think you posted your loss/objective function earlier so we should take the gradient of that. But it was too hard to take the gradient of sorry.